# install USB 3.0 express card under linux (Arch Linux) (tried adding kernel parameter intel_iommu=off pciehp.pciehp_force=1)

Tags: arch-linux, usb, kernel-modules, pci

I'm trying to install a CSL USB 3.0 express card to my Arch Linux system.

However, when I do this, I get the following error message:

> xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
>
> xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: HC died; cleaning up

I googled and tried adding the following kernal parameters

```
intel_iommu=off
```

Some sites also mention

```
iommu
```

**This unfortunately didn't help me anything.**

I also tried to add:

```
pciehp pciehp_force=1
```

And tried to do

```
sudo modprobe pciehp pciehp_force=1
```

But Arch Linux complains that it doesn't find the kernel module `pciehp`.

I didn't find any information on how to install `pciehp` kernel module on Arch Linux. Some say, it is build into the kernel or something.

**debug information:**

**kernel version:** `4.16.6-1-ARCH`

[**`dmesg`** with debugging `xhci_hcd` enabled and with `xhci_hcd` greped](https://pastebin.com/raw/qpTZSkAY)

**`lspci -nn`:**

```
05:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1912:0015] (rev 02)
```

[**`dmesg`** (old without `xhci_hcd`-debugging and withouth `grep`](https://pastebin.com/raw/rcMUJDA9)

**References to places with people working on the problem:**

Linux mailing list:

- [Re: kernel does not receive any USB3.0 plug/unplug events from the Renesas upd720202 chipset](https://pastebin.com/raw/qpTZSkAY)
- [Patches for "Renesas uPD72020x workaround" don't work](https://pastebin.com/raw/rcMUJDA9)

Other sources:

- [Linux Kernel Bug Tracker - bugzilla.kernel.org](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199627)
- [Arch Linux forum on bbs.archlinux.org - discussion regarding the issue](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=236806)

Comment: Please edit question with the line in `lspci -nn` that identifies the problematic controller card. Also edit question with any other messages related to this card that show up in `dmesg`. (Indent 4 spaces for proper formatting).

Comment: @dirkt I did! You may kindly edit the question posting an excerpt from the pastebin.

Answer (score 3):

Hm. Unless I'm overlooking something, it looks like the controller is initialized *twice*:

```
[    5.195136] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    5.195145] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    5.202621] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: hcc params 0x014051cf hci version 0x100 quirks 0x00000090
....
[    5.203568] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    5.203572] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    5.204014] usb usb4: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
```

The [Renesas Product Info](https://www.renesas.com/en-us/products/usb-assp/upd720202.html) seems to say that while there are two ports each for each USB 3.0/USB 2.0 legacy root hub, there's only one root hub, so I don't understand what's going on.

If two instances of `xhci_hcd` are trying to control the card at the same time, then of course this will go wrong.

Next thing I'd do is to look at the `xhci_hcd` source, and recompile with debugging support. This requires programming experience, so if you don't know how to do that, alternatively file a bug report on whatever kernel bugtracker handles `xhci_hcd`, even if the devs just tell you that I am stupid and the repeated initialization is normal.

**Edit**

Inspecting the debug messages, this here looks very odd:

```
[    2.423207] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: Finished xhci_run for USB2 roothub
[    2.423420] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: Endpoint 0x81 ep reset callback called
[    2.423547] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: set port power, actual port 0 status  = 0x2a0
[    2.423563] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: set port power, actual port 1 status  = 0x2a0
[    2.423613] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    2.423616] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    2.423621] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: // Turn on HC, cmd = 0x5.
[    2.426468] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: Finished xhci_run for USB3 roothub
[    2.426630] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: Endpoint 0x81 ep reset callback called
[    2.426798] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: set port power, actual port 0 status  = 0x2a0
[    2.426819] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: set port power, actual port 1 status  = 0x2a0
[    2.426893] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: remove, state 1
[    2.427674] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: USB bus 2 deregistered
[    2.427731] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: remove, state 1
```

So after initializing everything, a reset gets called on both the USB 2.0 and the USB 3.0 root hub. They get removed, and then the driver tries to initialize the whole thing again (which is the second initialization I saw). Only this time it fails hard.

In the kernel source code, function `xhci_endpoint_reset` has comments along the lines "We might need to implement the config ep cmd in xhci 4.8.1" and "For now just print debug to follow the situation".

So this is definitely a case for the kernel developers. Make sure to amend the bug report with the debug output.

Comment: [The bug-report is now here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199627). **It worked now** at least once (maybe through software update). I don't now if it will work continuously - i hope so. Do you mean [this](https://burzalodowa.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/how-to-enable-and-tune-dynamic-debugging-for-xhci/) by debugging xhci_hcd? Thanks for your effort and help!

Comment: It didn't help. It still does not work after reboot. I furthermore get the error-message `[    6.561655] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Unable to initialize device.` and the mouse lags, when the express card is inserted, when it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, the link you gave for enabling the debugging is the right one. If you mean by "it didn't help" that enabling debugging didn't solve the problem: Of course it doesn't, it isn't meant to. But now you should have lots of debugging messages in `dmesg` that can help in narrowing down the problem. Put it in a pastebin so I can have a look. Unplug all USB devices you don't need when booting with debugging enabled, they'll only clutter up the log. The lagging is expected if the kernel is busy writing lots of messages.

Comment: No, I mean that it worked exactly once, I could stick a USB-drive to it and everything, but this was the only time. When I rebooted it didn't work anymore. I don't know why it worked and don't know why it doesn't work now anymore. I figured out, that my kernel has CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG enabled and found debugfs mounted rw, but I cannot write to it tough. It says permission denied, even though I am logged in as root. Do you know what the problem is and why I can't write to it debugfs as root with rw mounted?

Comment: Debugfs exposes various "files" which are just interfaces to parts of the module. The majority of them are not writeable, and just give information. Some may be writeable, but it's not a good idea to write to them unless you **exactly** know what you are doing, which requires reading the module code. You can't create new files (this doesn't make any sense at all). But what we need is not debugfs access, what we need are more debugging messages in dmesg to get some idea what's happening.

Comment: [The guide for debugging `xhci_hcd` I found, which you approved in your first comment](https://burzalodowa.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/how-to-enable-and-tune-dynamic-debugging-for-xhci/) works with debugfs.Specifically it asks me to run `echo 'module xhci_hcd +p' > <debugfs>/dynamic_debug/control`.I tried running `echo 'module xhci_hcd +p' >> <debugfs>/dynamic_debug/control` (notice the double >>). If the config-line is correct, this should be safe. So I would need write access to the `control`-file. If this is not the way to go, I would need to find another method/guide than `dynamic debugging`.

Comment: I however wondered about the lines in the `<debugfs>/dynamic_debug/control`-file looking different from the line `module xhci_hcd +p`. So I don't know, _if_ this line in the above guide is correct?

Comment: I think I made the [`xhci_hcd`-debugging](https://pastebin.com/raw/qpTZSkAY) work [see this link](https://pastebin.com/raw/qpTZSkAY)!

Comment: Thanks, I added the latest `dmesg` to [https://bugzilla.kernel.org](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199627). Is [https://bugzilla.kernel.org](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199627) the url to go or should I use another bugtracker?

Comment: Bugzilla @ kernel.org looks good.

Comment: Update: There are two kernel developers on [bugzilla.kernel.org](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199627), who seem to have made progress recently.

Comment: Make sure to post an answer once it's verified that the quirk is working.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same or a similar problem. Did open a thread here:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1784837

My testing came to the result, that it showed up with kernel 4.12.8-1-ARCH.
And in another laptop, this same card works - now with linux 4.15.15.

Comment: I have kernel version `4.16.6-1-ARCH` running.

Answer (score 1):

With the newest current kernel `5.0.10-arch1-1-ARCH` the card works. But on my system it only works, when I insert the device before booting.

**Other solutions:**

In the above link, Xavier says [here](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb/msg169534.html), that he found the workaround of adding the kernel-parameter `pci=nomsi` to his boot options. I did not investigate it yet further.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `iommu=soft` to the grub's parameters solved my problem